# insert new DOM between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following part of DOM:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="div-1"></div>
  <!-- here new DOM -->
  <div id="div-2"></div>
</div>
```

I need to insert new part of DOM between "div-1" and "div-2".

How I can do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) on `div-1`

```
$('#div-1').after('<div id="new">new div</div>');
```

or use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) on `div-2`

```
$('#div-2').before('<div id="new">new div</div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div-1').after('<div>new content</div>')'
```

or

```
$('<div>new content</div>').insertAfter($('#div-1'));
```